# Spring-MVC: Upload a file

Tags: spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I'm having some troubles uploading a file with Spring-MVC 4.2.1..

Here is the code for the endpoint:

```
  @CrossOrigin
  @ApiOperation(value = "Add an attachment to a video", notes = "Add an attachment to the video with a specific id.", response = String.class)
  @ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Succesfully attached."),
    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Request could not be authorized."),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error."),
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Malformed request.") })
  @RequestMapping(value = "/attachment/add",
    produces = { "application/json" }, 
    consumes = { "multipart/form-data" },
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<String> addAttachmentVideo(@ApiParam(value = "ID of the document", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "docId", required = true) String docId,
 @ApiParam(value = "file detail") @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,
    @ApiParam(value = "Name of the attachment", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "attachmentName", required = true) String attachmentName)
      throws NotFoundException {

        VideoControllerMock dummyClass = new VideoControllerMock();

        ResponseEntity<String> dummyResponse = dummyClass.addAttachmentVideo(docId, file, attachmentName);

        return dummyResponse;
  }
```

I also gives you the function `addAttachmentVideo`:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> addAttachmentVideo(String docId, MultipartFile file, String attachmentName) {

    String responseString = "{\"response\": \"File with name " + attachmentName + " has been attached to document " + docId + ".\", \"file\": {\"size\": " + file.getSize() + "}}";

    // Prepare the headers
    HttpHeaders headers = headersClass.getMultiPartHeaders();

    // Response to send back
    ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>(responseString, headers, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

    return response;
  }
```

And finally the function `getMultiPartHeaders`:

```
  public HttpHeaders getMultiPartHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    //headers.add(CREDENTIALS_NAME, "true");
    //headers.add(ORIGIN_NAME, "http://localhost:8080");
    headers.add(METHODS_NAME, "GET, OPTIONS, POST, HEAD");
    headers.add(HEADERS_NAME, "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    headers.add(CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/form-data");
    headers.add(MAX_AGE_NAME, "3600");

    return headers;
  }
```

Sadly, I cannot change the code for the endpoint.. It's generated automatically with swagger-codegen.. But I can change the two other functions..

If I use this, I get this error:

```
[WARNING] 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Request processing failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: 
is a MultipartResolver configured?
```

Does anyone knows how to get rid of this problem?? The thing is I don't know how to configure this MultipartResolver..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure a `CommonsMultipartResolver` like so (in your mvcconfig):

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(-1);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by mvcconfig??